# T-SQL grant login for attach or detach databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about security in SQL Server.

Is it possible to create a login with only authorization to attach or detach databases?

I don't want it as sysadmin.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation, you will see that for [attaching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) a database we need:

> Requires CREATE DATABASE, CREATE ANY DATABASE, or ALTER ANY DATABASE
>   permission.

and for [detaching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/detach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017):

> Requires membership in the db_owner fixed database role.

If you check the [security hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-hierarchy-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) and [download](https://aka.ms/sql-permissions-poster) the `Chart of SQL Server Permissions`, you can check what other permission a user will have if he has any of the above permissions.

For example, if he has `ALTER ANY DATABASE`:

[image]

Basically, these rights are on the top of the security hierarchy and if you allow a user the ability to `attach` database, ze will be able to do other operations overt it, too.

If you don't want to make the user member of `sysadmin` role, that's OK. You can make the user member of `dbcreator` role:

[image]